# Loading images on UIScroll from documents directory

Tags: iphone

I have different images for portrait and landscape, I fetch the images from the Document directory, their is  a total of 62 images. 31 Landscape images having 1015x745 dimensions and 31 Portrait having 751x1024 dimensions. All the images loading on the simulator but when i run the same code within the device the application crash. It load either only the portrait on landscape images.

```
int porWidth = 768, lanWidth = 1024;
int i=0;
    for (CatalogIndividuals *cat in self.array)
    {
        UIImageView *imageView1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(porWidth*i +5, 0, 757, 964)] autorelease];
        imageView1.tag = porImage+i;

        NSString *fullPath =[self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cat.portraitImage]];

        imageView1.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[fullPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"/"]]];
        imageView1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        UIImageView *imageView2 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lanWidth*i +5, 0, 1015, 620)] autorelease];
        imageView2.tag = lanImage+i;

        NSString *tempPath = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cat.landscapImage]];
        NSString *str = [tempPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"/"];

        NSLog(@"imageView1 fullPath = %@",str);
        imageView2.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:str]];}
```

I think there is some memory leak problem. please help if anybody has any solution.

Comment: are you storing these imageViews in some data object/dictionary/array? Can you add some more code of this loop.

Comment: Jim is very right, at run time limited amount of memory is present with app.

Comment: We are storing all the image reference in an array and then fetch images from the document directory.

Comment: ok, will you please provide sample code for doing the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's about 350MB worth of images.  You don't have a memory leak, you're just using far too much memory.  This is a mobile device, not a desktop computer, the resources available to you are limited.

You shouldn't be loading all the images at once, you should be loading them dynamically as you scroll through the content.  Take a look at the sample code Apple provides for `UIScrollView` to see how you can use tiling to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks, we will try. but if you have some sample code please share with me.

Comment: will you please provide the link of sample code. I found a sample code "Scrolling" from the developer library. In this code only five images are used and we will use the same code but not found any solution.

Comment: Also the size is not 350MB, we are using the jpg images with 72dpi and the total size of images is 10MB.

Comment: That's file size.  The JPEGs are stored uncompressed in memory.  DPI is meaningless in this context.  I've since read that if you use `imageWithContentsOfFile:` it does not store the images uncompressed, so you may have better luck using that instead of the convoluted `NSData` method you are currently using.

Comment: i try to use the imageWithContentsOfFile instead of NSData but still the problem remain same. Also refer the code from developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite but i can't find the solution yet. please help

Comment: Did you actually try the tiling approach?

Comment: thanks jim. I resolve the issue. now i dynamically add the image on the imageView, and not all the images simultaneously.